# Webpack You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, with sue

Tags: webpack, vue.js, css-loader, vue-loader

I created my project with Webpack and using Vue.js in development, but I can't inject `<style>` in the Vue template.

It got me

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (18:5)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| 
| 
> body {
|   background-color: red;
| }
```

this is my `webpack.config.js`

```
  ...
  module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: "vue-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
        }
      },
    ]
  },
```

and also my `App.vue`

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <counter></counter>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Counter from "./app/Counter.vue";
export default {
  name: "app",
  components: {
    counter: Counter
  }
};
</script>

<style>
body {
  background-color: red;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Which version of vue-loader is used?

Comment: @raina77ow my cue-loader is version 15.2.4

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Had the same issue. Looking into the docs for [vue-loader](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/#manual-configuration) css needs rules too.

Install the packages `vue-style-loader` and `css-loader`

Add the following to your `rules` section in `webpack.config.js`:

```
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [
      'vue-style-loader',
      'css-loader'
    ]
  },
```

Comment: I don't understand why this isn't documented somewhere in the Typescript, Vue, or GitHub/vue-loader domains.  Spent waaaay to long looking for this solution.

Comment: Same here. Spent waaay too much time looking for this. Browsed through many git issues, other stackoverflow questions, and this is what finally worked.